# How to mention the author of a message in another message

Tags: node.js, discord.js, replit

I am using repl.it to develop a bot. I am trying to make a command that makes the bot behave like this:

> Someone: *!slap @someoneelse*
>   Bot: *@Someone slapped @someoneelse*

How can I get the bot to mention `@someone` **without** using ID? Multiple people will use the command and I can't just use ID since it will only work with one person. I haven't found anything that helped me, and the documentation was no help either. Hopefully, I can get help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users and members have a [`.toString()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) method that is automatically called every time they are concatenated with a string: that means that if you type `"Hey " + message.author` you will get `"Hey @author"`

That's how I would do the command:

```
// First store the mentioned user (it will be undefiend if there's none, check that)
let mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
// Reply by directly putting the User objects in the string: 
message.channel.send(`${message.author} slapped ${mentionedUser}`);
```